# ¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo aquí? "[...] era conocido de todo el que supiera mover un alfil en un tablero"

Tags: subjuntivo, literatura

La partida de ajedrez juega un papel clave en *El amor en los tiempos del cólera*, de Gabriel García Márquez. ¿Por qué razón es necesario el subjuntivo en este fragmento?

> Fue esa la época en que vino Jeremiah de SaintAmour, ya con sus rodillas
>   muertas y todavía sin el oficio de fotógrafo de niños, y antes de tres meses era conocido de todo el que **supiera** mover un alfil en un tablero, porque nadie había logrado ganarle una partida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Todo el que" es una frase pronominal que no se refiere a personas específicas, sino que es inespecífica, similar a "quienquiera". Todos conocemos cómo funciona sintácticamente "quienquiera". La NGLE dice en su punto 22.6.2a:

> Los grupos sintácticos constituidos por relativos inespecíficos suelen denotar personas o cosas no identificadas, lo que justifica que se construyan con subjuntivo. Los relativos inespecíficos se interpretan como TÉRMINOS DE ELECCIÓN LIBRE, por lo que, como los demás miembros de esta clase, poseen interpretación existencial o universal en función del contexto.

Distinto sería si el autor hubiera optado por el plural, en cuyo caso se habría referido a todos los que **sabían** mover un alfil en un tablero, o sea, a todas las personas que efectivamente sabían jugar al ajedrez. Al usar "todo el que", mucho más elegante que el plural, la mención a los conocedores de ese juego queda abierta a todos sus eventuales aficionados.